# Not receiving Apache Camel Event Notifications under the smallest load

Tags: events, apache-camel

I have extended EventNotiferSupport, and set the isEnable() to respond True for all events.  I have a notify() that logs what events I receive and the corresponding Exchange ID for the event.

I have added my ExchangeMessageNotifier with this.context.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(this.exchangeMessageNotifier);

I run my program under basically no load, sending 1 message at a time 1 second delay between messages into Camel to send out.  Everything works the way I expect.  I receive my events everything looks good.

I decrease the delay between messages to 0 milliseconds, and I find that 1 out of approximately 20 messages I fail to receive one of the Events, (Often the Completed event).

Add a second thread sending at the same rate and I don't get any events for any messages.

What am I missing?  I've done searches and I don't find anything that I need to do differently.  Is there something I am missing?

I am using Apache Camel 2.16.3, and moved to 2.18.1 still see the same behavior.

Comment: I am setting the following for events to handle:

`    @Override
    protected void doStart() throws Exception {
        this.setIgnoreCamelContextEvents(true);
        this.setIgnoreExchangeCompletedEvent(false);
        this.setIgnoreExchangeCreatedEvent(false);
        this.setIgnoreExchangeFailedEvents(false);
        this.setIgnoreExchangeRedeliveryEvents(false);
        this.setIgnoreExchangeSentEvents(false);
        this.setIgnoreRouteEvents(true);
        this.setIgnoreServiceEvents(true);
    }`

Comment: I add that class as a bean in blueprint. Then after enabling the events I want you should see the events appearing in your logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found my own answer. Part of the fun of inheriting code without any informaiton.

In your implementation of the EventNotifierSupport you need to override the doStart() method and configure the EventNotifierSupport for what events you wish to receive.

```
    protected void doStart() throws Exception {
  // filter out unwanted events
  setIgnoreCamelContextEvents(true);
  setIgnoreServiceEvents(true);
  setIgnoreRouteEvents(true);
  setIgnoreExchangeCreatedEvent(true);
  setIgnoreExchangeCompletedEvent(false);
  setIgnoreExchangeFailedEvents(true);
  setIgnoreExchangeRedeliveryEvents(true);
  setIgnoreExchangeSentEvents(false);
}
```

This is in addition to doing the following:

```
public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
  return true;
}
```

Which enables you to determine if you want a particular event, out of the selected groups you had set in the doStart().

Once these changes were in I was receiving consistent events.